# How to handle images in input fields in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm creating a reusable component using Reactstrap. What I want to do is display an image in the input field as below
[image]

**What happens is this**

[image]

How to get the image to the front??

InputFieldWithImage.js

```
import {
  Input,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';
import { Form, FormGroup } from 'reactstrap';
import Amy from './../../assets/images/Amy.png';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';

function InputFieldWithImage(props) {
  const [inputType] = useState(props.type);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log('Input.js');
    // console.log(inputValue);
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
    if (props.onChange) props.onChange(event);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          type={inputType}
          value={inputValue}
          name="input-form"
          onChange={handleChange}
          class="inputclass"
        />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append" >
          <Image
            style={{ width:50, height: 50, marginLeft: -70 }}
            src={Amy}
            roundedCircle
          />
        </InputGroupAddon>
      </InputGroup>
    </>
  );
}
export default InputFieldWithImage;
```

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply handle this issue using CSS by giving the picture "position: absolute"
and the Input container "position: "relative".